# R tryCatch() - referencing return of expr() in finally?

Tags: r, try-catch-finally

I am trying to write a function to handle execution of batch jobs,
logging errors and stats of the job results.

Is there a way to reference returning value of expr block, from finally block?

```R
my_do <- function(FUN, ...){

  result <- tryCatch({
      FUN(...)
    }, 
    error = function(e) {
      message("error.")
    },
    finaly = {

      # how can I reference the returning value of FUN(...) in finally block?
      # so for example, I can write code like this:

      message(paste("Result dimensions:", dim(expr_result)))
    },
  )

  return(result)
}
```

Comment: If `FUN(...)` throws an error, there is no return value from it. I think you might be interested in restarts but your example is neither complete/reproducible nor sufficiently specific.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Roland, yes as I tried to minimise my original code, I did miss a few bits that makes the questioin a little vague. originally my code had a safety mechanism to return alternative data frame in case of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `tryCatch` return value is being saved into a variable, such as

```r
x <- tryCatch({ 1; }, finally = { message("value is ", x); })
# Error in message("value is ", x) : object 'x' not found
```

then the answer is *no*, since the `x` object does not exist when `tryCatch` executes `finally=`.

However, the code block operates within the parent environment, so you can do this instead:

```
tryCatch({ x <- 1; }, finally = { message("value is ", x); })
# value is 1
x
# [1] 1
```

This relies on the return value being set without error. If there's an error somewhere in the execution, then ... obviously there will be no value to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you Evans for making it clear, that without saving the result to an object, I can't reference output from expr block!
I falsely assumed there may be a way to reference the return of expr block somehow.

I altered my original code as per your suggestion, to make it work as I wished. 
Hope you have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that this is not the best way for using `finally`.

There are following best practices for use `finally` (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html):

> It specifies a block of code (not a function) to run **regardless of whether the initial  expression succeeds or fails**. This can be useful for clean up (e.g., **deleting files,  closing connections**). This is functionally equivalent to using on.exit() but it can  wrap smaller chunks of code than an entire function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the brilliant articles by Hadley! will read further there.